# Подключение к MySQL-серверу объекта mysqli в режиме MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу CLI утилиту на PHP. С MySQL работаю через библиотеку mysqli. Использую mysqli в объектном режиме. Скрипт подключается к удаленной серверу MySQL и читает из базы кучу информации (до 500 Мб). Возникает острая необходимость уменьшить трафик между скриптом и MySQL-сервером. Логичнее всего это делать используя подключение с компрессией MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как, используя класс mysqli, поднять подключение через MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS? Ведь, подключение подымается при создании объекта (в конструкторе), а там негде устанавливать флаг компрессии.

Он устанавливается в mysqli_real_connect(), но, к возможному моменту использования этой функции, подключение уже инициировано конструктором mysqli.

Процедурный стиль работы с mysqli прошу не предлагать. Если других вариантов нет - это очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У mysqli в объектном режиме есть [`real_connect(...)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-connect.php). Гляньте на последний возможный параметр - flags, через него можно передать MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS

```
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'root', '1', 'tmp_data', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS));

printf("Server version: %s\n", $mysqli->server_info);
```

Если не указывать в конструкторе параметров, то он пытается подключиться с параметрами по-умолчанию, поэтому вместо конструктора целесообразно использовать [`mysqli_init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.init.php) (в данном случаем он не будет пытаться подключиться), так как [`mysql::init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.init.php) - вовсе не static метод (поэтому вызвать его, по-моему, можно только унаследовавшись от класса mysqli и в конструкторе вызвать его как `parent::init()`, хотя хрен редьки не слаще - класс-наследник все равно придется создать через new).

С использованием `mysqli_init()` это будет выглядеть так:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'root', '1', 'tmp_data', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS));

printf("Server version: %s\n", $mysqli->server_info);
```

P.S. Посмотрите в сторону [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), может понравится :)

Comment: <p>Странно, но подключение через <em>mysqli_init()</em> заработало и без наследования:</p>
<pre>$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'root', '1', 'tmp_data', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS));</pre>
<p>Выходит что mysqli_init() возвращает экземпляр класса...</p>

Comment: Да, если присмотреться на тип возвращаемого значения mysqli::init() и mysql_init(), то можно заметить что они возвращают экземпляр класса mysqli.